# Moving an object up with an IMU sensor in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to simulate an IMU sensor attached to a hand in Gazebo, so I can extract the imu data (angular velocity and linear acceleration) to estimate the position/movement. I also wrote a keyboard_controller to move the hand. I do that through publishing to the topic "gazebo/set_model_state".  When I try to move the hand it moves to one position and then falls to the ground. But I want it to stay there, so I can move it to all directions and extract the positions. I could achieve that with deactivating gravity but then I won't get any values for linear acceleration. Also when I do a roll/pitch or yaw movement everything works fine, just for up, down and so on I don't get linear acceleration data.

Is there a way, I could move my model without deactivating gravity?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, maybe you can try to publish to the "gazebo/set_model_state" topic in a certain frequency to simulate a continuous command to your virtual hand. Then the hand will not fall.